# Change leaflet map opacity outside circle of point

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet

[Geoapify search nearby places](https://apidocs.geoapify.com/playground/places) feature highlights the area that is located within the given result , i need to know how to add this feature to leaflet map so the given radius area containing nearby places  is highlighted  from another areas ,is there any solution to do this in react leaflet map ?

[image]

```
 useEffect(() => {
         const map = useMap();
         L.circle([lat, lng], { radius: 200 }).addTo(map);
      }, []);

    const Map = () => {
      return (
        <MapContainer 
          center={center} 
          minZoom={1} 
          zoomControl={false}
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright"></a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          /> 
          
        </MapContainer>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Definitely not built-in, but you may be able to find something in the plugins.

Answer (score 2):

A way would be to use [L.Donut](https://github.com/Falke-Design/L.Donut) and draw a circle with hole around the marker:

```
L.marker(map.getCenter()).addTo(map);
var donut = L.donut(map.getCenter(),{
    radius: 20000000000000,
    innerRadius: 100,
    innerRadiusAsPercent: false,
    color: '#000',
    weight: 2,
}).addTo(map);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/JX3VdzxnGXGoOerr